Display a list comma separated taxonomy terms with "and" as final separator in Wordpress
I'm trying to output a list of custom taxonomies on Wordpress where the final separator is an &.
I have three potential taxonomies a post could be in: Category 1, Category 2, and Category 3. Some posts will be in 1 category, some will be in 2, some will be in 3.
What I'd like is to include the list of which categories the post is in on the page with it. However, if a post is in all three categories I don't want it to say: 'Category 1, Category 2, Category 3'.
I would like it to say: 'Category 1, Category 2 and Category 3'.
My taxonomy slug is 'project-category', and I'm trying to make use of wp_sprintf to output the list. But I can't get it to work properly.
This is my code at the moment. It's not outputting anything, but I can't figure out why not.
<?php

  $post = get_queried_object_id();
  $term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post, 'project-category');
  echo wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $term_obj_list);

?>

I've also followed this older question. It works when there is more than one category, but when there is just one category it still adds 'and' before it.

Are you asking how to ltrim() &, or are you filing a bug report, or do you want a native PHP solution?

The wp_sprintf_l function also has a corresponding hook of the same name. I’ve never used this and I don’t have a reference copy of WordPress for testing, but you should be able to supply a value for the between_last_two key. You might also find between_only_two valuable, too. There is a note that "Ampersands and entities should be avoided here", but looking at the code I’m not certain what the problem would be.

@mickmackusa Sorry for not being more clear with this. What's happened is I'm using the code I pasted above, but I'd like some help troubleshooting why it isn't working. I'll edit the original question to try and help.

Thanks @ChrisHaas. I can work with that, however it's getting wp_sprintf_l to actually display the values that I'm struggling with. It sounds like this should be quite straightforward but I keep getting errors.

Your question started with the & for the last, so that's what we assumed you needed fixing. Instead, your problem is that you can't get wp_sprintf_l to work, right? If so, it might help to remove the other parts from your question, and we'll solve this first. Also, "I keep getting errors" isn't helpful, please always post any errors you receive. My guess is that wp_list_pluck will be helpful in this scenario, where you'd take the output of get_the_terms, pluck just the names, and pass that to wp_sprintf_l.
